# модальная форма через ajax не отправляет письма

Tags: php, ajax, post, email, form

Есть форма

```
<div class="modal-section" id="modal_forms">
    <div class="modal-form swraps">
      <div class="modal-form-wrapper">
        <div id="modal_close" class="close-link">x</div>
        <div class="top-form-block w-form">
          <form id="emailmodal" name="emailmodal" class="modal-form-box">
           <input type="hidden" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="citymodal" value="City"  id="citymodal">
          <label for="namemodal" class="field-label">Ваше имя*:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-input w-input sinput" maxlength="256" name="namemodal" placeholder="Введите ваше имя..." id="namemodal" required="required">

          <label for="phonemodal" class="field-label">Ваш телефон*:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-input w-input sinput" maxlength="256" name="phonemodal"  placeholder="Введите номер..." id="phonemodal" required="required">




          <input type="submit" value="ЗАПИСАТЬСЯ!"  class="form-cta-button w-button">

            <div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" data-name="Checkbox" class="w-checkbox-input" checked required="required" disabled>

            <label for="checkbox" class="checkbox-label w-form-label">Оставляя свои персональные данные, Вы даете добровольное согласие на их обработку. <a class="privacy-link">Подробнее</a>*</label></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Обработчик submit

```
    // Variable to hold request
    var request;

    // Bind to the submit event of our form
    $("#emailmodal").submit(function(event){

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form1 = $(this);

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form1.serialize();

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "formmodal.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
         $('#emailmodal')[0].reset();

    });


request.always(function () {
 $('#emailmodal')[0].reset();
    });

});
```

Форма выводится в модальном окне. Такая же форма (айди полей и формы другие, но код обработчика такой же, и отдельный идентичный php) отправляет без проблем. у этой формы отправка стопорится, модальное закрывается, и вместо отправки кидает на site.ru/?namemodal=asdad.... подскажите что не так.

Сделал привязку на все формы. то есть не $("#emailmodal").submit(function(event){ а $("form").submit(function(event){ - результат тот же. форма в модальном переадресовывает на сайт.

кажется проблема в модальном, вот код

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#phonemodal").inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99");
    $("#phone2").inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99");

    $('a#go').click( function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(400, 
            function(){ 
                $('#modal_forms') 
                    .css('visibility', 'visible') 
                    .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); 
        });
    });

    $('#modal_close, #overlay').click( function(){ 
        $('#modal_forms')
            .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'}, 200,  
                function(){ 
                    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut(400); // 
                }
            );
    });
});
```

именно оно не дает отправить пост через аякс.

Comment: Если при отправке у вас стоит `event.preventDefault();` а переадресация происходит на сайт, как вы описали, значит попросту событие не привязано к форме, возможно вам стоит использовать не `$("#emailmodal").submit(function(event){` а `$(document).('submit','#emailmodal', function() {)`

Comment: @RifmaMan не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

У вас синтаксическая ошибка в конце кода JS функция `request.always(function() {` код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
request.always(function() {
   $('#emailmodal')[0].reset();
});
```

З.Ы. из-за этого событие и не цепляется на форму и идет перенаправление когда вы жмете отправить, будьте впреть внимательны и смотрите в Консоль браузера, там ошибка показана при загрузке страницы (Клавиша F12 обычно -> Консоль)

Comment: Спасибо, убрал давно ее, но здесь в коде есть. сейчас поправлю. тут скорее всего проблема в модальном. оно не работает, а вот форма на странице отправляет без проблем